# Positioning of device towards a target like Panorama images app in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sensors, gyroscope, sensormanager

I hope most of you have used the Panorama Image option in Camera app. They ask/force the user to move the device in one direction e.g. if you take 1st image then you move to 2nd image and then it will show you a **TARGET BOX** and when you reach that box the image is captured again and so on.

[Panorama Images Example in Samsung Galaxy s2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tt67TdnNM9c)

I am interested to know that how can we achieve this functionality so that we can set target for user to move the device towards a certain direction. Which sensors can help to achieve this functionality and factors are involved?

Just a simple example is that we make a simple game in which we get an arrow towards the Target Box and when we get that target box in focus we get some score etc.

Please guide me on this, thanks.